# ComboBox not accessible with JAWS

Tags: c#, uwp, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

When focussing on a ComboBox, JAWS says that you can alter the selection by using the arrow keys on your keyboard. But when altering, the user gets no audio feedback of the selected item.

Narrator handles this correctly.

I've tried:

-Adding AutomationProperties to the Datatemplate of the combobox:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ComboOCRLanguageTemplate" x:DataType="data:OCRLanguage">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Culture.DisplayName}" AutomationProperties.Name = "{x:Bind Culture.DisplayName}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
</DataTemplate>
```

-Creating a custom combobox to try using a live region:

```
class AccessibleComboBox: ComboBox
{
    public AccessibleComboBox()
    {
        AutomationProperties.SetLiveSetting(this, AutomationLiveSetting.Polite);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up)
            RaiseLiveRegionEvent();
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up)
            RaiseLiveRegionEvent();
    }

    private void RaiseLiveRegionEvent()
    {
        if (FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged))
        {
            var AP = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(this);
            AP.RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the same code and used RaiseLiveRegionEvent() in my custom combobox class, but the windows Narrator does recognize it still. Were you able to figure out the problem! Thanks.